# Swagger operation.Responses.Add could not find reference of resolve pointer?

Tags: c#, .net, swagger

Currently, I'm setting up a Swagger page for the API I'm working on. This API has default behavior for error handling. The error handler always gives the same response object.

```
    public class ErrorDetails
    {
        public int StatusCode { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
```

When I open a response block, I receive the following exception:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tl8kz.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFOfz.png)
And the schema value is empty.

The code I use for Swagger generation to create the default response information:

```
 public class GeneralExceptionOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
    {
        public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
        {
            var schema = context.SchemaGenerator.GenerateSchema(typeof(ErrorDetails), context.SchemaRepository);
            var content = new Dictionary<string, OpenApiMediaType>()
            {
                {"application/json", new OpenApiMediaType { Schema = schema  } }
            };

            operation.Responses.Add("401", new OpenApiResponse() { Description = "Unauthorized", Content = content});
            operation.Responses.Add("403", new OpenApiResponse() { Description = "Forbidden", Content = content});
        }
    }
```

Currently, I'm lost and have searched for a long time for an answer to this issue I have.